# Execute scope function from service parameter

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

I am trying to create a service when I can set my formSubmit.

For example. In controller A I call "service.setFormSubmit(doThis(obj))" and in controller B I call "service.getFormSubmit()". Where it will execute the function doThis(obj) in controller B.

**UPDATE - Re-formulated question.**

I have 1 view where I want to edit or create a category. This means I need a dynamic ng-submit. I want to to this in the controller. So like this:

```
$scope.editCategory = function(obj) {
     $scope.formSubmit = 'editCategory'
}
```

And on the create I want to change the formSubmit var to createCategory of course.
So I can make a difference between creating and editing the category.

Is this possible? Would be really nice if someone has a way to do this..!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't get it, maybe try rephrasing or add some code

Comment: I've added some code example

Comment: @guidsen it still doesn't make too much sense.  Services are singletons so you can store whatever you need to and get it back.

Comment: @lucuma how would you make a service that will pass a ng-submit variable between two controllers then?

Comment: If you are trying to share functionality across controllers the logic should probably be in the service and not the controller.

Comment: I return $rootScope.editCategory() in the service and I have editCategory in my controller, but it is undefined..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing around strings which need to be eval'ed, use the service to share functionality directly between controllers.

The service can be dirt-simple:

```
.factory('MyService', function(){
  var service = {};
  return service;
});
```

Once injected and assigned to scope variables in both controllers you have an intermediary unit which can act as a modifiable channel for cross-controller collaboration.

```
.controller('FirstController', function($scope, MyService){
  $scope.service = MyService;
})
.controller('SecondController', function($scope, MyService){
  $scope.service = MyService;

  $scope.service.create = function(obj){
    console.log('Creating');
  }

  $scope.service.edit = function(obj){
    console.log('Editing');
  }
})
```

From the scope of `FirstController`, you can now call the function also available on the scope of `SecondController`:

```
<div ng-controller="FirstController">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="button.type"> Toggle create/edit<br/>
  <button ng-if="button.type" ng-click="service.create(obj)">Create</button>
  <button ng-if="!button.type" ng-click="service.edit(obj)">Edit</button>
</div>
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/dy5eyb8LrVrRJimeOsXq?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't reloading the page you can create an encapsulated variable in your service.  Your set call would assign the value passed to that variable and your get call would return that variable to the caller.

One way I have achieved passing the data is to submit the form using the service and return a Json result to the service.  Store the Json object in the encapsulated variable on the return and then pass a success or failure to the controller.  When successful, let the controller redirect the view which will redirect using angular routing and ng-view.  Once the new view, along with the new controller is loaded into the page, you can call the variable in your service to retrieve the data on the next controller.

Example Code:

```
app.factory('service', function ($q, $http) {
    var savedData;

    return {
        loadData: function() {
            return data;
        },
        search: function (parameters) {
            var searchURL = '/MVCController/Search?parameter1=' + parameters.one +
                '&parameter2=' + parameters.two;
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            $http.get(searchURL).success(function (data) {
                savedData = data;
                deferred.resolve(true);
            }).error(function(data) {
                data = 'An error occurred while searching: ' + data;
                savedData = data //(if you want to save the error)
                deferred.reject(data);
            });

            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
});
```